# An administrator does not receive mailing emails: a new contact is created

Tags: civimail, joomla

An administrator does not receive mailing emails. His e-mail address is strictly the same in his contact form and Joomla! user profile.
When testing the mailing, CiviCRM creates a new contact with this address.
In the test group in which his contact details are displayed, no recipient appears in the mailing draft.
If I test with my address, everything works correctly: I receive the test emails and I am the recipient of the test group.

Joomla! 4.4.1 | CiviCRM 5.57.3

Comment: I am a little confused by the above. can you access the db - if so look for the civicrm_uf_match table which is what should be connecting the User with the Contact.

Comment: I am too! I really don't understand how it is possible.Yes, I can access to civicrm_uf_match table and IDs are like in the contact. The Joomla ID and the CiviCRM ID are matching.

Comment: i don't know joomla - but i would not expect the CMS ID to match the CRM ID in general

Comment: You're right. What I meant was that the IDs in the civicrm_uf_match table correspond to the respective Joomla and CiviCRM IDs.

Comment: This being the case, we tested again: sending created a new contact. I then merged the both contacts (admin and the new contact) and the problem no longer seems to arise !?!

Comment: In civicrm_uf_match table, the new CiviCRM ID replace the old one.

Comment: Not sure, but if you have solved your problem then pls add as an Answer. Noting that in cases where there are duplicate contacts both with users it is usually necessary to then delete the user that belonged to the contact that gets put in trash via the merge - otherwise the CMS user just hangs around 'orphaned' and causes headaches if the person is still trying to log in using that email. ps if you have logging on the the log of the uf_match table can offer good insights in to what has happened in the past

Comment: I'll do it, I have to verify with the user everything's all right.
Both contact haven't both users. The user test the mailing and another contact is created, but no other user is created. Then I merged both contact and the contact ID change in civicrm_uf_match table, but user ID is always the same, also in the civicrm_uf_match table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution: After sending a test, a contact is created. This contact must then be merged with the J! administrator contact and the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long-standing issue, but by sheer chance, I fixed it today: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29212

This occurs when you send an email to a contact that has "do not mail", "bulk mail opt out", or "deceased" set.  With this patch, those folks simply don't get an email.